# What's the difference between "wasserdicht" and "wasserfest"?

Tags: meaning, difference, adjective

What is the difference between "wasserdicht" and "wasserfest"?

With which one can you dive and with which one can you walk in the rain?

Comment: You are talking about wristwatches?

Comment: not only wristwatches, also clothing materials

Answer (score 11):

"**wasserfest**" means that the material is not destroyed by water; the plastic in a sieve is "wasserfest", while the sieve is not "wasserdicht"

"**wasserdicht**" means that the material will not let water pass through; a diver's watch is "wasserdicht"

"**wasserabweisend**" means that a fabric will repell water but let water through if the pressure is strong enough; usually this means that clothing will keep you dry when there are only a few drops of rain, but you will get wet in heavy rain

Comment: Since a garden hose is usually also *wasserdicht*, a marker might be a better example. The *wasserfest* variant is the so-called permanent one, and can only be removed by using solvents like ethanol. The opposite is *wasserlöslich* (soluble in water), where you can remove the writing by wiping it off with a wet towel.

Comment: Is the wasserabweisend the same like spritzwasserfest? I have found online: spritzwasserfest=splash proof.

Comment: @cornejo No. "Spritzwasserfest" means that a short splash of water won't destroy something like an electronic device that you take to the beach. "Wasserabweisend" means that a clothing fabric has been treated or specially woven to repell water that has only a light pressure. Basically both words mean something similar but are used in different contexts.

Comment: In wristwatches we differ between "wasserdicht" which means a watch you can submerge under water e.g a diver's watch, and "wassergeschützt" which means a watch that whithstands moist and water that isnt under pressure.